# Current Password and new password validation in account page

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript

In account page how to validate that the current password and new password are not the same?

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

To check, that the user changed his password, you need his old password - this is not possible, because it is hashed.

So the other way around, hash the new password:

use `\Mage_Core_Model_Encryption::validateHash($password, $hash)`

where `$password` is the new password and `$hash` is the old password.

If the exception is thrown, the password was changed.

```
public function validateHash($password, $hash)
{
    $hashArr = explode(':', $hash);
    switch (count($hashArr)) {
        case 1:
            return $this->hash($password) === $hash;
        case 2:
            return $this->hash($hashArr[1] . $password) === $hashArr[0];
    }
    Mage::throwException('Invalid hash.');
}
```

Comment: this code is Ok but I want to check whether current password and new password are same  or not if same error message should display else  password should change how to do this

Comment: Yes, catch the exception, if it is thrown, the passwords differ, if nothing is catched, the passwords are the same

Comment: @vidhya were you able to achive it, Have to do same customisation in magneto2

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
<form .....>
......
<input type="password" class="validate-password" name="userpassword"/>
<input type="password" class="validate-cpassword" name="comparepassword"/>
....
</form>
```

Hope you understand this just use two classes `validate-password` and `validate-cpassword`

Comment: I think that checks if the values are the same. The OP wants the other way around.

Comment: yes @Marius I understand wrong.